# How to define foreign key only in an entity without primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

hi my tables are as follows:

1- **medical_company**:

- medical_company_id **foreign key** on **account_entity** table **account_entity_id** column (not a pk)
- column1
- column2
- column3

2- **account_entity**:

- **account_entity_id** (pk)
- column1
- column2
- column3

**ENTITIES:**

1- **MedicalCompany:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "medical_company")
public class MedicalCompany implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "medical_company_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Long id;
```

}

2- **AccountEntity:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_entity")
public class AccountEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "account_entity_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Long id;

}
```

i want to make **medical_company_id** in medical_company table as foreign key without defining a primary key, how to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities must have an ID. That's mandatory. Whether this ID is an actual PK in database or not is not important (although I don't see any reason not to define it as a PK), but the ID must be immutable and unique across all rows of the table.

Comment: ok then how to make that primary key act as a foreign key and refer to other table's primary key ?

Comment: The OneToOne annotation javadoc has an example. You must use the MapsId annotation. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html. The Hibernate doc also has explanations: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5617

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate wont allow to define entity with out PK. So you should declare medical_company_id as a primary key and make it foreign key for account_entity table.